# In Verilog, how do I take a 16bit input and break it down into 4, 6, and 6 bits?

Tags: verilog, microprocessors

I've done a lot of Googling and Stack Overflowing. I can't seem to word the question properly I guess. I'm trying to learn verilog and I found a tutorial that is building a microprocessor. The step I'm on right now is the instruction decoder.

- Takes a 16 bit input
- First 4 bits raise a flag that corresponds to the instruction (ex. MOV, ADD, ADDI, SUB, NOT, AND, OR, etc.)
- Last 12 bits break down into 6 and 6 for holders to do the operation

[Here's a crappy diagram,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bS8d.png) if the way I explained it didn't make sense.
This is a beginner level project, which is why I'm upset I can't wrap my head around this. I would just have 3 different inputs but I don't think signals are sent 4, 6, and 6 at a time.

I know the standard is to also have some code in your question but I literally don't know where to start.

Comment: The terminology you need is 'bit slice from vector'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure that using this tutorial is god for the beginner level. You should start with something much easier, like printing 'hello world' first. But here is the starting point for this one:

1) you are getting an instruction which is 16 bit wide:

```
module decoder(input [15:0] instruction, input clk, ...);
```

2) according to your diagram (usually bit '0' is on the far right and bit '15' is on far left) it looks like bits [5:0] belong to the second param, bits [11:6], to the second and bits [15:12] to the code. So, you can write something like the following:

```
reg [3:0] opcode;
reg [5:0] param1;
reg [5:0] param2;

always @* begin
    opcode = instruction[15:12];
    param1 = instruction[11:6];
    param2 = instruction[5:0];
end
```

This will give you a starting point. Now for the module you would need to figure out the outputs you need, and clocks. Clock is used in hardware to synchronize operations and create state machines. After you got your opcode and params, you would need to figure out what to do with them.

Now you can have some decoding logic:

```
always @(posedge clk)
    case (opcode)
    4'b0100: op <= mov;
    4'b0101: op <= add;
    ... 
    endcase
```

I hope it helped.

Comment: This did help! And to address the first part of your statement. I'm well past the Hello World of verilog. This is the last lesson.